# What happens if we expand the alphabet of a given Turing Machine?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

[image: Turing Machine M]

If we expanded the alphabet Sigma = { 0, 1, u, > } to Sigma' = { 0, 1, 2, u, > }.    How would the table change?     We're just learning about Turing Machines in class and I'm a bit confused. Is the table in the picture calculated in some way?

Comment: The table is not "calculated in some way". It is determined by the programmer with the goal of executing a certain program. The programmer has complete freedom regarding what the table looks like.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s a table of transitions, and it determines what the program does when it encounters a given symbol on its tape while in a given state.  This program, if I’m reading it right, accepts strings containing two consecutive 1 symbols before the first space.

If there were another symbol, it would be necessary to define what the program would do on encountering them.  For example, to ignore them, there would be a pair of transitions saying that, if the program is in state s1 and reads a 2, it should stay in state s1 and move to the right, and that if it is in state s2 and reads a 2, it should stay in state s2 and move to the right.

Comment: I see, so what I'm confused about is: When we introduce another symbol, we have to (as you said ) define what the program would do on encountering them. Can I define anything I want?  For example, if the program is in state s1 and reads 2, write 0 and move to the right. and in state s2, if it reads 2: write 0 and move to the right.

Comment: Sure.  The Turing machine you end up with might or might not do anything useful, but that is a valid Turing machine (if you also specify which state it will be in).